# New laptop. Why am I unable to test an app I'm writing on my iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I recently purchased a new laptop for development (I am a registered paid developer), switching from my old MacBook Air that I always did development on. I had no problem testing apps from that laptop to my iPhone 5, but now that I have a new laptop I can't seem to test apps on that same iPhone.

I'm sure it's added as a device to develop on as it's been used for that before, but I selected "Add to member centre" anyway.

Under Preferences > Accounts, I added my developer login, selected View Details and under Signing Identities I added for both iOS Distribution and iOS Development but it always just lists all my provisioning profiles in the lower "Provisioning Profiles" section, but my "Signing Identities" section always seems empty.

Whenever I run the app and select my device as the target I get "No code signing identity found" error. When I click "Fix Issue" it spins for a bit, then brings the exact same error screen up.

What should I do?

Comment: add your Provisioning and development certificates again, Quit Xcode and run again.

Comment: @Virussmca Is there a way to do that from Xcode or must I do it from the dev centre?

Comment: Just open dev centre, Download your Provisioning and development certificates, and just double click on it. and make sure there is entry in KeyChain also.

Comment: did you try to import developer certificate into your system. If not then do this first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, you didn't mention anything about the `Keychain`.
You need to import the Private Private Keys from your old machine to your new laptop.

1. Open the 'Keychain Access Application' and select the 'Keys' category.
2. Control-Click on the private key associated with your iPhone Development Certificate and click ‘Export Items’ in the menu. The private key is identified by the iPhone Developer: public certificate that is paired with it.
3. Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file format (password protected).
4. Copy the p12 file to your new machine and install it there.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to export your development keys from your old machine's keychain and import them onto the new machine. Otherwise, you will need to generate new keys for the new machine and then replace the dev certificates.

The dev certs generated from the ADC center are only half the equation. The keys in the keychain are the other.

Hopefully not too short an answer.